# Javascript: Add a class definition after page load

Tags: javascript, class, npm, build, web-component

While using native web components I need to be able to add Class definitions after page load, when I have unknown new types of components entering the DOM.

---

EDIT: A little explanation:

Web components are defined with a class:

`customElements.define('my-new-tag', myNewtagClass);`;

So if you want to add a new type of component in the DOM, the corresponding class needs to be defined, and if I understood well you can't define a global class programmatically, you need to have it defined in the root document/scope.

---

Aa a pure JS solution at the moment all I found is to create my class as a string and to add it in a script in the head of the document.

But as a result I need to write my class like this:

```js
let myClassString = `
class myClass {
  ....
}`;
const sc = document.createElement('script');
sc.setAttribute('type', 'text/javascript');
sc.innerHTML = myClassString;
window.document.head.appendChild(sc);
```

And as a result it's not very convenient in the IDE...

Is there a way to do this in the build process (I use TS and webpack)?

I mean taking the code from a file (where the class will be defined in a normal way), and using it as a variable somewhere else?

Comment: ??? **Why** do you have to create the class from a string? You can create a class in a function and return it. Without knowing what problem you're trying to solve, it's going to be hard for anybody to help.

Comment: @Pointy I added some context

Comment: No, that is not true; you can define a class in any scope. A function can return a class as a value.

Comment: A class defined in a function can use the closure scope as "private" context, so you can write functions and pass parameters to them, and the functions can make classes that are configured by the particular parameters passed.

Comment: @Pointy Thanks! I was completely mistaken... When you define a class in a function you create it as a string, right? You can't "compose" a class otherwise, no?

Comment: Well, again, if I don't know what *exactly* you need to do to build a class, I can't answer the question. You do not, definitely not, have to build a class as a string; you build it with a perfectly normal `class` declaration statement. You can add functions to the class prototype after it is built. There are all sorts of things you can do to manipulate a class. Building things from raw strings in JavaScript is very rarely necessary, like almost never.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I also don't get why you want to create a class with a **string**

Here is ***some*** code I pulled from my components;
dynamically creating classes/methods/Web Components

```html
<script>
  console.clear();
  const createElement = (tag, props) => Object.assign(document.createElement(tag), props);
  class BaseClass extends HTMLElement {
    constructor(name = null) {
      super();
      this.name = name;
    }
    connectedCallback() {
      this.hello();
    }
  }
  const createClass = (extendFrom, ...args) => {
    class Klass extends extendFrom {
      constructor() {
        super(...args);
      }
    }
    Object.assign(Klass.prototype, {
      ["hello"] : function() {
        this.innerHTML = `Hello from <b>${this.name}!</b><br>`;
      }    
    });
    return Klass
  }
  const createComponent = (name, defaultClass = BaseClass) => {
    customElements.define(name, createClass(defaultClass, name));
    document.body.append(createElement(name, {
      title: name,
    }))
  }
  document.onclick = () => {
    let count = document.body.querySelectorAll("[title]").length + 1;
    createComponent("new-component" + count);
  }
  createComponent("my-comp1");
  createComponent("my-comp2");
</script>
click document!<br>
```